# popoverPresentationController ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, popover

while reading in the apple documentation i have came across this property in the UIViewController class

popoverPresentationController
 Property
The nearest popover presentation controller that is managing the current view controller. (read-only)

Declaration
SWIFT

```
var popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController? { get }
```

Discussion
If the view controller or one of its ancestors is managed by a popover presentation controller, this property contains that object. This property is nil if the view controller is not managed by a popover presentation controller.

If you created the view controller but have not yet presented it, accessing this property creates a popover presentation controller when the value in the modalPresentationStyle property is UIModalPresentationPopover. If the modal presentation style is a different value, this property is nil.

i didn't quit understand what this property will return and what is the use of it.
if anybody can explain it better to me and i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a view controller is presented as a popover, it has a `popoverPresentationController` whose methods and properties you might need to access. For example, the way you set a popover's `passthroughViews` is by setting the popover presentation controller's `passthroughViews` property.

Comment: Thank you. i appreciate your help